# Using TransitOptions Literal in GoogleMaps DistanceMatrix API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Good day!

I am very new to JavaScript, and have come to it as I think it can help automate a project I am working on. Essentially, I am mapping two Brazilian cities (Vitoria and Florianapolis) and looking for the transit times between an array of points. GIS tools are suitable for driving distance/time, but these cities do not have transit options (the TravelTime platform does not work in Brazil yet).

What I believe I can do is utilise the Google Maps JavaScript API and the Distance Matrix Service to build an array of Origin/Destination (O/D) pairs. And I think I have done that part with some introductory learning and the help of the Google Maps example. My plan is to expand both the Origin and Destination variables with the figures I need once I have this item sorted out.

Where I'd like to go next is to use the TransitOptions literal to always have the departure time set to 8 AM (i.e. rush hour). I don't want the data to change based on what time of day I run the script.

Attached is where I've got to so far, but I am 99% sure I am using the TransitOptions incorrectly:

```
      <body>
    <div id="right-panel">
      <div id="inputs">
        <pre>
var origin1 = {lat: -27.524, lng: -48.642};
var destinationA = {lat: -27.594, lng: -48.554};
        </pre>
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>Results</strong>
      </div>
      <div id="output"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
    let departurewindow = new Date('2020-03-10T08:00:00')
      function initMap() {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds;
        var markersArray = [];

        var origin1 = {lat: -27.524, lng: -48.642};
        var destinationA = {lat: -27.594, lng: -48.554};
        var destinationIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?' +
            'chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=D|FF0000|000000';
        var originIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?' +
            'chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=O|FFFF00|000000';
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -27.50, lng: -48.5},
          zoom: 10
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
          origins: [origin1],
          destinations: [destinationA],
          travelMode: 'TRANSIT',
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false,
          departureTime: departurewindow,
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status !== 'OK') {
            alert('Error was: ' + status);
          } else {
            var originList = response.originAddresses;
            var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
            var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
            outputDiv.innerHTML = '';
            deleteMarkers(markersArray);

            var showGeocodedAddressOnMap = function(asDestination) {
              var icon = asDestination ? destinationIcon : originIcon;
              return function(results, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                  map.fitBounds(bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location));
                  markersArray.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    icon: icon
                  }));
                } else {
                  alert('Geocode was not successful due to: ' + status);
                }
              };
            };

            for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
              var results = response.rows[i].elements;
              geocoder.geocode({'address': originList[i]},
                  showGeocodedAddressOnMap(false));
              for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                geocoder.geocode({'address': destinationList[j]},
                    showGeocodedAddressOnMap(true));
                outputDiv.innerHTML += originList[i] + ' to ' + destinationList[j] +
                    ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in ' +
                    results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }

      function deleteMarkers(markersArray) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
          markersArray[i].setMap(null);
        }
        markersArray = [];
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`departureTime:`  should be a field in [TransitOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#transit_options) object literal and not a field in [DistanceMatrixRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_requests) object literal.

`var transitOptions = {departureTime: departurewindow};`

```
service.getDistanceMatrix({
      origins: [origin1],
      destinations: [destinationA],
      travelMode: 'TRANSIT',
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false,
      transitOptions: transitOptions  
    }, function(response, status) {});
```

Here's a [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/o2caf367/) of the snippet above.